# Lag/Jank When Scrolling with Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, lag

Having some jank/lag when scrolling in chrome on my parallax site located at http://mattsandifer.com

The parallax code is taken from: http://www.minimit.com/demos/parallax-backgrounds-with-centered-content

It was going smoothly and then all of a sudden it just started to become very choppy when scrolling.

The images are on the larger side but nothing too crazy. I'm thinking it's a JS issue but I'm not sure. I tried disabling the retina image but there was no change.

Any way to reduce the load time or lag?

Appreciate any help with this!

**edit**: found a link to a blog post saying hardware acceleration is the key. They provided this code:

```
 window.onscroll = function(e) {

  // note: most browsers presently use prefixes: webkitTransform, mozTransform etc.

  var parallax = document.getElementById('parallax-background');

  parallax.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px,' + (window.scrollY/2) + 'px, 0px)';

}
```

Not sure which element to plug in there for my code though.

Comment: how do I turn this off and is it recommended to do so, will it have any negative affects? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, but I need javascript for the parallax effect, right? Ok I found that in the code 

    `function parallaxPosition(e){
    var heightWindow = $(window).height();
    var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();`

Comment: A-ha! That one works much better, thanks! Really appreciate the help. 
Now if only I could get it working on mobile I'd be set.